# Subset data from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a pandas dataframe with columns `Cust_email,visit_date_time, transaction_date_time`. `Cust_email` contains the email id of the customer, `visit_date_time` contains the timestamp when the customer visited the product and `transaction_date_time` contains the transaction timestamp if the customer bought that product else the field remains empty.

Now, I want to subset the pandas (all columns) which contain only those email ids which made atleast one transaction, i.e, I want to remove all those email ids which have null entries for all their `visit_date_time,transaction_date_time` combination

Comment: So you want `df[df['transaction_date_time'].notnull()]`?

Comment: No, For example, `abc@gmail.com` has three records out of which two records have no `transaction_date_time`. But since, he has made one transaction, I want his other two records too.

Comment: so you want `df['df['Cust_email'].isin(df.loc[df['transaction_date_time'].notnull(), 'Cust_email'].unique())`?

Comment: @EdChum Thank you. That works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) to test for membership of your customer ids, we filter the df first of those transactions that didn't complete, get the customer id's from those rows and pass to `isin`:

```
df['df['Cust_email'].isin(df.loc[df['transaction_date_time'].notnull(), 'Cust_email'].unique())
```